# Programmatically and completely delete button from MFC toolbar

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar

I have a document within MFC C++ application. I need to delete one the buttons from the particular `CMFCToolbar` within a code (not resources) completely, even preventing a user to restore the button via toolbar customization dialog. At this moment I use `RemoveButton` method of `CMFCToolbar` but it only makes the button invisible and it can be restored via toolbar customization dialog that is not an option for me at this time. I will be very glad if you suggest something that can help me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two internal lists in CMFCToolBar that are used to reset the Buttons upon customization.
They are named **m_OrigButtons** and **m_OrigResetButtons**.

You may need to derive your own class and delete the buttons with the specific IDs from there.

But better: Never to include such a button on the first time when the toolbar is created!

Comment: Wait, wait. What do you mean under: "Never to include such a button on the first time when the toolbar is created!". Do you mean that I should exclude it from resource files and create it in code. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I will try these lists first.

Comment: Yes! You are not forced to use a resource to create the toolbar. The toolbar resource is just an array of some integers that is uses in conjunction with a bitmap. It isn't difficult to write your own "SetButtons" routine that might exclude some buttons. We do the same, because of license restriction some users should never see specific buttons.